# Is there any way to reuse Visual Studio 2015 SDKs while installing Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I've been recently upgrading to VS2017 and was wondering if there was any way I can use the SDKs I've already had downloaded for VS2015 ?

UPDATE: I think it should be possible for standalone SKDs like UWP, Xamarin.... !

Answer (score 0):

SDKs are bind to VS versions strictly. Don't attempt to do so and make sure you have enough disk space to install Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: What about the ones downloaded as Standalone ? I guess they aren't VS version specific ?

Comment: @Pratik can you update your question with which are the SDKs you care? It might be case by case, but many do rely on VS version.